# element[attr=value] selector doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When trying to use a custom attribute of topColor, I cant get 2 classes to use 2 pseudo elements. Code below.

HTML

```
<li class="nav-item" topColor="D24726">Hello</li>
<li class="nav-item" topColor="008A00">Hello</li>
```

CSS

```
.nav-item:hover[topColor=D24726]{border-top: 2px solid #D24726;}
.nav-item:hover[topColor=008A00]{border-top: 2px solid #008A00;}
```

I have also tried this:

```
.nav-item[topColor=D24726]:hover{border-top: 2px solid #D24726;}
.nav-item[topColor=008A00]:hover{border-top: 2px solid #008A00;}
```

When I hover over the first nav-item with top color D24726, it  works. However, it does not work for the second item. Any ideas?

Also if its possible I want it to be done in CSS not jQuery unless its necessary

Comment: A question should be edited only to clarify the *question*. Answers are to be posted as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS selectors to:

```
li.nav-item[topColor='D24726']:hover {
    border-top: 2px solid #D24726;
}
li.nav-item[topColor='008A00']:hover {
    border-top: 2px solid #008A00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FIXED * *

Added quotations around the attribue values and all works ok

Comment: You put all that effort into your question only to answer it like this? What's the point then?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would like to shed some light here, using <s>`topColor`</s> is not a valid attribute, so consider using [`data-`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) prefix for your custom attributes.

And you will require quote around the attribute values, why is that so?

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

So, your first selector will work as the value of your attribute doesn't start with a number i.e `D24726` where as second will fail as it starts with a number i.e `008A00` so you will need quotes for second and not for first.

So it is better to use quotes around the values, as even if any special characters like `- / &` etc are used, your selector will fail.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XAAaH/)